# PyQt, QThread: GUI freeze with large amount of SIGNAL from another thread (QListWidget massive update)

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, pyqt4, signals-slots, qlistwidget

I have an app that starts the GUI and performs "the heavy part" of the code in another thread using QThread. In this thread I emit a SIGNAL that is connected to the GUI Class and that performs addItem on QListWidget.

There are a massive "signaling" from this thread to the GUI and it "freeze".

Is there a way to avoid this? Have I to use another mini GUI in different thread only for QListWidget?

Thanks

EDIT:
This is the thread that execute the heavy logic

```
class YourThreadName(QThread):
    def __init__(self, some variables):
        QThread.__init__(self)

    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()

    def run(self):
        # Here there is a for cycle that emits a SIGNAL
        for ... :
            ...
            self.emit(SIGNAL("needed_variable"), needed_variable)
            ...
```

In the GUI Class there are some methods, particularly:

```
class GUI(QtGui.QMainWindow, GUI.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GUI, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def ... (self):
        ...

    def start_main_code(self):
        self.new_thread = YourThreadName(some variables)
        self.connect(self.new_thread, SIGNAL("finished()"), self.done)
        self.connect(self.new_thread, SIGNAL("needed_variable"), self.show_variable)
        self.new_thread.start()

    def show_variable(self, data):
        self.QListWidget_object.addItem(data)

    def ... (self):
        ...
```

Comment: Please read the guidance on [ask], and how to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Edited, please take a look now. Thanks

Comment: That is not a [mcve].

Comment: This is the problem, you have all the element, if you don't want to help me stop commenting

Comment: I don't know how to add others information because if I remove that SIGNAL the GUI works without any problem. So the question is: is it possible to update a QListWidget with 50/100 item per second without freezing the GUI?

Comment: I have posted an answer to show you what an MCVE should look like. I have based it on the information you have so far provided. Please test the code on your system. If it does not reproduce the problem, there must be some vital information missing from your example code and/or description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script below is a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example based on the information currently given in your question and comments. It emits data from a worker thread every 10ms and updates a list-widget in the GUI. On my Linux system (using Python-3.6.3, Qt-4.8.7 and PyQt-4.12.1) it does not block or freeze the GUI. There is obviously some flickering whilst the list-widget is being updated, but I am able to select items, scroll up and down, click the button, etc. And if I increase the sleep to 25ms, I don't even get any flickering.

**UPDATE**:

The performance can be improved by using [setUniformItemSizes](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistview.html#uniformItemSizes-prop) and sending the messages in batches. On my system, after a slight initial delay, the list populates with fifty thousand items almost instantly.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Worker(QtCore.QThread):
    message = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)

    def run(self):
        batch = []
        for index in range(50000):
            if len(batch) < 200:
                batch.append(index)
                continue
            self.message.emit(batch)
            batch = []

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.listWidget = QtGui.QListWidget()
        self.listWidget.setUniformItemSizes(True)
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Start')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.listWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.worker = Worker()
        self.worker.message.connect(self.handleMessages)

    def handleMessages(self, batch):
        for message in batch:
            self.listWidget.addItem('Item (%s)' % message)

    def handleButton(self):
        if not self.worker.isRunning():
            self.worker.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(600, 50, 200, 400)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: In your example the GUI seems to be responsive but at some point the list become blank and I see all the lines only at the end. This happens also with 25 ms of delay. If I increase the delay this behaviour happens later but is always present.

The good point is that the GUI doesn't hang.

Is there a way to avoid the problem? What is the difference between your implementation and mine?

Comment: Ok, the problem is simple: I have to print about 758 element each second, on the console the total printed elements are 30859 in 40,7317 seconds. So I have to log one element each 1.32 ms. The Qt widget is a crap so it is impossible. Is there another widget/way for that kind of problem?

Comment: It is impossible to answer your first question, since you have still not provided an mcve that reproduces your specifc problem. I have updated my answer with an example that drastically improves the overall performance on my system.

Comment: Your new code is very impressive, I have to use it on my code for testing. Many thanks for now